# Incosistent addition behavior in np.array vs list when using int vs float type

Tags: python, numpy

Using Python 3.10.8.

I was a bit puzzled after finding about this behavior, and it probably has a good explanation, but it is still strange...

for a list:

```
l = [1, 2]
l[0] += 0.5
```

gives l[0] -> 1.5

for a np array:

```
l = np.array([1, 2])
l[0] += 0.5
```

gives l[0] -> 1

for a np array:

```
l = np.array([1, 2.0])
l[0] += 0.5
```

gives l[0] -> 1.5

I believe this is because the list can hold different data types and np.array holds always the same data type.

First case list has int values but += converts the result to float because it receives a float
right hand value

Second case np.array has int values so += converts the right hand value to int rounding it to 0

Third case np.arry has float values (giving a single float value in the array converts the full array to float?) so adding 0.5 just does floating point addition.

If all my assumptions are correct I still find it something difficult to get along with...
Probably a good approach when working with this is to always use floating point values during the definition of np.arrays or specify the data type explicitly to make sure you get what you expect.